# XML transform. Selecting data blocks with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm selecting separate data blocks and output data in transformed XML. But somehow I can't get each block `<images>` separated... I'm getting all `<image>` elements in one.

As you can see it tranforms all `<images>` into one data block. I need it to output as seperate `<Images>` blocks. So it would be that first product has its own 2 images and second product has its own 2 images. Now it has all 4 images from all products.

Source XML:

```
  <products>
<product>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Batai CUBO TURIN S3 SRC ]]>
</title>
<long-description>Test
</long-description>
<colours>
<colour>
<images>
<image>
<url>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-turin-s3-src-1-1.jpg</url>
</image>
<image>
<url>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-turin-s3-src-4.jpg</url>
</image>
</images>
<modification>
<modification-title>
<![CDATA[ Dydis 42 ]]>
</modification-title>
<attributes>
<barcodes>
<barcode>
<![CDATA[ 6901106054109 ]]>
</barcode>
</barcodes>
</attributes>
</modification>
</colour>
</colours>
</product>
<product>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Batai CUBO TRENTO S3 SRC ]]>
</title>
<long-description>
Test2
</long-description>
<colours>
<colour>
<images>
<image>
<url>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-trento-s3-src-1-1.jpg</url>
</image>
<image>
<url>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-trento-s3-src-5.jpg</url>
</image>
</images>
<modifications>
<modification>
<modification-title>
<![CDATA[ Dydis 41 ]]>
</modification-title>
<attributes>
<barcodes>
<barcode>
<![CDATA[ 6901106114100 ]]>
</barcode>
</barcodes>
<manufacturer-code/>
</attributes>
</modification>
</modifications>
</colour>
</colours>
</product>
</products>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <root>
        <Products>
         <!-- Loop through each item -->
            <xsl:for-each select="product">

 <!-- parent item info. Info after barcode.  -->        
                 <!-- Informacija apie preke kuri atsikartoja kiekviename barkode ta pati  -->  
                <xsl:variable name="item-info">          
                        <xsl:value-of select="long-description"/>                          
                </xsl:variable>

<!-- Prekes pavadinimas kuris  kiekviename barkode yra tas pats  -->    
                <xsl:variable name="item-name">                 
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </xsl:variable>

              
                    <!-- a product for each variant. loop each EAN. -->
                <!-- Si dalis loopinasi per kiekviena barkoda kuri yra iteme. Pakankamai sudetinga. -->
                <xsl:for-each select="//modification">
                    <Product>
                        <Product_id/>
                        <SKU/>
                        <Warehouse></Warehouse>
            <Barcode><xsl:value-of select="barcode"/></Barcode>
                        <Name>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$item-name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="modification-title"/>     
                        </Name>
<Description><xsl:copy-of select="$item-info"/></Description>
    
                            <Specifications>
                <spec name="Dydis"><xsl:value-of select="modification-title"/></spec>         
              </Specifications>
                        <Images>
                       <xsl:apply-templates select="//images/image"/>  
                        </Images>
                        <Units/>
                        <Price></Price>                       
                        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                        <Inventory_count/>
                        <Note/>
                        <Group1>STD.</Group1>
                    </Product>
                </xsl:for-each>
              
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Products>
    </root>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="//images/image">
    <Image>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Image>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I'm getting:

```
    <root>
       <Products>
          <Product>
             <Product_id/>
             <SKU/>
             <Warehouse/>
             <Barcode/>
             <Name>Batai CUBO TURIN S3 SRC Dydis 41 </Name>
             <Description>Test</Description>
             <Specifications>
                <spec name="Dydis">Dydis 41 </spec>
             </Specifications>
             <Images>
                <Image>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-turin-s3-src-1-1.jpg</Image>
                <Image>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-turin-s3-src-4.jpg</Image>
<image><url>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-trento-s3-src-1-1.jpg</url></image>
<image><url>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-trento-s3-src-5.jpg</url></image>
             </Images>
             <Units/>
             <Price/>
             <Currency>EUR</Currency>
             <Inventory_count/>
             <Note/>
             <Group1>STD.</Group1>
          </Product>
          <Product>
             <Product_id/>
             <SKU/>
             <Warehouse/>
             <Barcode/>
             <Name>Batai CUBO TURIN S3 SRC Dydis 41 </Name>
             <Description>Test</Description>
             <Specifications>
                <spec name="Dydis">Dydis 41 </spec>
             </Specifications>
             <Images>
                <Image>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-turin-s3-src-1-1.jpg</Image>
                <Image>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-turin-s3-src-4.jpg</Image>
<image><url>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-trento-s3-src-1-1.jpg</url></image>
<image><url>https://www.saugult.eu/images/uploader/ba/batai-trento-s3-src-5.jpg</url></image>
             </Images>
             <Units/>
             <Price/>
             <Currency>EUR</Currency>
             <Inventory_count/>
             <Note/>
             <Group1>STD.</Group1>
          </Product>
```

Comment: BTW the input data is thousands of products so I can't shrink the data that simle... Sorry.

Comment: What is the result that you want to get?

Comment: I did not follow your entire code. I am guessing the problem is that you are doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="//images/image"/>` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="../images/image"/>`.

Comment: The result I would like to get is:
<Product>
           ... 
         <Images>
            <Image>1st Image of 1st product</Image>
            <Image>2nd Image of 1st product</Image>
         </Images>
         ...
      </Product>
      
       <Product>
           ... 
         <Images>
            <Image>1st Image of 2nd product</Image>
            <Image>2nd Image of 2nd product</Image>
         </Images>
         ...
      </Product>

Comment: Dots is the data I'm getting right. The images are the problem. As i loop through each product I need to get they images seperatly. Now I'm getting them all.

Comment: I suggest you post a [mcve]. In your question, not in comments. Full (and minimal) code, not snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the prblem. The XSLT with solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <root>
        <Products>
            
            <xsl:for-each select="product">

                <!-- Pavadinimo selectinimo blokas  -->
                <xsl:variable name="item-name">                             
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>              
                </xsl:variable>
                <!-- Pavadinimo selectinimo blokas  -->
                
                <!-- Description selectinimo blokas  -->
                <xsl:variable name="item-description">                             
                        <xsl:value-of select="long-description"/>               
                </xsl:variable>
                <!-- Description selectinimo blokas  -->
                
    
                <xsl:for-each select="colours/colour">
                
                    <!-- Images selectinimo blokas  -->
                    <xsl:variable name="item-images">                          
                        <xsl:value-of select="images"/>             
                    </xsl:variable>
                <!-- Images selectinimo blokas  -->
                    
                
                    <xsl:for-each select="modifications/modification">
                        <Product>
                        <Product_id />
                        <SKU />
                        <Barcode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="attributes/barcodes/barcode"/>
                        </Barcode>
                        <Name>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$item-name"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="modification-title"/>
                        </Name>
                        <Description>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$item-description"/>
                        </Description>
                         <Images>
                            <Image>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="$item-images"/>
                            </Image>
                        </Images>
                        <Units />
                          <Price />
                          <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                          <Inventory_count />
                          <Note />
                          <Group1>STD.</Group1>
                        </Product>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    
                </xsl:for-each>
            
            </xsl:for-each>
            
        </Products>
    </root> 
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="/colours/colour/modifications/modification/modification-title">   
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```